# Inequivalent opposite quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Two integral quadratic forms<sup>1</sup> $f(x,y) = ax^2+bxy+cx^2$ and $g(x,y)=a'x^2+b'xy+c'y^2$, with $a, b, c, a', b', c' \in \mathbb{Z}$, are said to be *properly equivalent* if 
$$
f(x,y) = g(\alpha x + \beta y, \gamma x + \delta y)
$$
for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = +1$.

**The question:** Is there some well-known example of an integral quadratic form $(a,b,c) := a x^2+ bx y + c^2,$ which is not properly equivalent to the opposite form $(a,-b,c) = a x^2 - bx y + c^2$?

This question arose while reading section V of Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmeticae.
I have so far failed in finding an example.

---

<sub>1. Some definitions use $2b$ instead of $b$ in the RHS.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  2x^2 + xy + 3 y^2   $$

To get an example with $\Delta + 4$ a square but the form not equivalent to its opposite, it is necessary to use indefinite forms, which are more work.

$$ 9 x^2 + 3xy - 17 y^2 $$

........

Comment: Thank you. Is it too much to ask for an additional example for which $b+\sqrt{4+b^2-4ac}$ is an even integer? (or help in finding it)

Comment: Thank you very much!